# Unknown java type at runtime with Predicate

Tags: java, persistence, predicate

I am trying to use Predicate to build a query. Here is my entity:

```java
    public class MyEntity {
        private LocalDateTime date;
        private Integer amount;
        
        //Some other
    }
```

I also have a class that contains my criteria

```java
    public class EntityCriteria
        private LocalDateTime fromDate;
        private LocalDateTime toDate;
        private Integer minAmount;
        private Integer maxAmount;
    
        //Other properties and getters/setters
    }
```

To avoid having add manually a predicate for each criteria (1) Because there are a lot 2) So I can add a criteria without having to add its predicate), I run through list of criteria need to check (date, amount,...) and then I have a configuration file to tell if I need to use *equal*, *between* or something else and, in the case of *between*, the name of the lower and upper criteria in *EntityCriteria*.

```java
    criteriaList.forEach(criteria -> {
        String strategy = getStrategyFromCriteria(criteria);
        String field = getEntityFieldFromCriteria(criteria);
        
        switch(strategy) {
            case "between":
                String lowerCriteriaName = getLowerCriteria(criteria)
                String upperCriteriaName = getUpperCriteria(criteria)

                // Something like lowerValue = getValueFromName(lowerCriteriaName)
                // Something like upperValue = getValueFromName(upperCriteriaName)
                Predicate predicate = cb.between(root.get(field), lowerValue, upperValue)
    });
```

I have no issue with *equal* since it asks an *Object* as parameter but *equals* need the type of the matching attribue in *MyEntity* and I can't figure how to do it in a way where it could take *LocalDateTime* or *Integer* in the same code. I would need something like a dynamic cast and be able to declare *lowerValue* and *upperValue* no matter the type.

Do you have any idea?